# I am resigning as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I have been trying to write this post for weeks. This is not the [magnum opus](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/magnum-opus) that I hoped it would be, but it will have to suffice. I have resigned as moderator of English Language Learners effective today and I won’t be contributing to Stack Exchange (SE) until the company stops being evil. Deciding to leave has been difficult, mostly because I really enjoy the ELL community and working with the other people on the moderation team.

Some of you may be aware that a respected moderator of six different SE sites was removed abruptly from her moderator position on all six sites purportedly for violating the Code of Conduct, although I have seen no evidence of behavior that would merit such a severe action. You can find out more about that in her post on Meta: [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/273494).

From my perspective, Monica was unfairly singled out when others’ behavior was just as bad or worse. Then, the consequences of the violation far exceeded what would be expected based on written policy and past actions. The unethical [icing on the cake](https://www.woodwardenglish.com/icing-on-the-cake-idiom-meaning/) was breaking with long standing policy to publicly humiliate and defame the person being punished. In response to the backlash from the community, multiple “[sorry, not sorry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sorry,_not_sorry)” [apologies](https://web.archive.org/web/20191222000507/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology) were posted. One equated revoking Monica’s moderator privileges without explanation and maligning her in public with unsubstantiated accusations as “shipping at 6 PM on Friday”. Someone seems to have forgotten that there is a real person on the other side of the screen. A statement was made that SE was not interested in “relitigating the past”, which seems an odd thing to say when there wasn’t any due process followed in the first place. I can’t in good conscience associate with people who treat other people that way, especially when they seem to think the only thing they did wrong was time it badly.

I am not resigning because of the [changes to the Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/273494). There is nothing required that this community isn’t already doing, which is being welcoming and respectful toward everyone. The ELL community is one of the most helpful and friendly communities on the Internet and I hope it will stay that way. I have enjoyed being a part of this community and I have learned a lot from both the askers and answerers. I know not everyone is sad to see me go; if it were otherwise, I’d think that maybe I didn’t do enough of the hard but necessary things being a moderator requires. I am sorry that Snailcar, Em. and Maulik are going to be stuck with more work. It’s been a pleasure working with them and an honor serving this community.

[Be excellent to each other.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096928/?ref_=ttqt_qt_tt)

I will retain my diamond until elections can be held (probably in January) just in case the remaining moderators need some emergency backup.

I am happy that Monica was able to reach a settlement with Stack Exchange. That doesn’t change the things that caused me to no longer want to participate on Stack Exchange sites. If anything, [the company’s statement about that agreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio?cb=1) makes me more confident that I made the right decision. The inability to acknowledge that it was wrong to demod Monica and sincerely and unreservedly apologize for it is a foreshadowing of future issues that I don’t want to be around for.

Comment: Thank you for all you have done to support the ELL community, the broader community, and your fellow moderators.  I'm sorry your efforts fell on deaf ears at SE. :-(

Comment: I'm sorry that ELL has lost a fair-minded, intelligent, patient, and dedicated moderator. I'm even sorrier that you have left because you no longer like nor trust  upper management. You have been fantastically important in the campaign to reinstate Monica and getting the company to see sense but only one site counts for them, and that's Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm sorry to see you leave.  Had I known you were considering this move, I would have advised you against it.  Having gone down this path myself, I can tell you that all it does is remove any remaining influence you might still have with the corporation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I appreciate that. I have only stayed this long because I felt obligated to try to  drag SE away from the dark side. It’s apparent to me from discussion in the moderator-only spaces that further effort is a waste of my time. Stack Overflow is headed exactly the direction management wants it to go. They don’t care about anything that is not SO or users who aren’t developers (unless they’re in a marginalized group worth virtue points), and I would like to enjoy the holidays with my family instead of [annoying pigs](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/07/10/sing-pig/) :)

Comment: It might interest you to know that I asked for reinstatement a couple of weeks ago, and was told I was banned from returning as a moderator for one year due to the suspension I received on Meta.  I haven't lost any sleep over it; I told them I wouldn't be asking for reinstatement again.

Comment: I too am deeply saddened by this turn of affairs. So far as I'm concerned, you really have been one of the very best moderators on ELL. If even *you* can't fit in, what hope is there for awkward bastards like me?

Comment: Thank you Monica, Mari-Lou, Robert, and FumbleFingers - Online it's sometimes difficult to know whether you have had a real impact or if it's all just "Internet points". I feel like [the cops in the Pirates of Penzance](https://youtu.be/pmBq_xtuOUM?t=268 "YouTube clip of the song") during [When the Foeman Bares his Steel](https://www.elyrics.net/read/d/d_oyly-carte-opera-company-lyrics/when-the-foeman-bares-his-steel-lyrics.html "text lyrics"); I keep saying I'm going to go but I seem be be having trouble actually doing it. (Yes, Yes, I go! *But you don't go!*)

Comment: A policeman's lot is not a nappy one. You have been everything one can hope for in a moderator: effective, patient and good-humoured. ... But I'm afraid you're right. I was hoping the grownups in the room would bring The Corp to its senses--jeeze, all it had to do was say "Hey, we did something stupid, but we're going to undo it". Guess not, and the ship is deserting the sinking rats. Enjoy your family.

Comment: Hey Colleen, I'm sorry to learn of things coming to this point. You've hold up long enough. Anyway. If I may, please refer to the comment I left to S.R.'s post [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/when-the-chips-are-down?cb=1#comment12701_5098). The invitation is also extended to you. I'm sure our team would be glad to have you with us.

Comment: @ColleenV I wanted to say thanks for the bounty. I see you are giving bounties on Meta left and right. Are you planning to delete your Meta account, like Robert Harvey just did?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I guess I have plenty of good company in penalty box ;)

Comment: [Q177](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334345/223820) has been deleted @DalijaPrasnikar I suppose we'd better not post any further comments. Sigh... I'm sure every comment posted by every suspended user is monitored by an app or programme.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar No, I don’t see any reason to delete any of my accounts. I’m not as active as I once was, and I don’t really need the reputation on Meta for anything  so I might as well spend it :) Besides, even if I’m not active, I would like to keep my profile around with information about how Monica was treated.

Comment: I am glad you are staying. Too many people had left one way or the other.

Comment: Whatever else is going on, nothing takes away from the good times of friendly chats with snails, chemical symbols and others in the robot’s chat room. :)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I wouldn’t say I’m staying, I’m just not disassociating myself from my past contributions or giving up my ability to moderate ELL until there is a replacement for me. I purposefully held off on making the decision to stop contributing until I let go of the anger so I would act out of a sense of what is right and fair (for me, for ELL, and for the other ELL moderators). I accept that the people whose actions made me not want to contribute any longer will not notice my absence, and nothing I do will change that, so there’s no point  in making a stink as I leave.

Comment: Yes,”I am not resigning because of the changes to the Code of Conduct.” You decided whatever the consequence is between Monica and the company. Could you show me the determination and brevity that you are going to resign and set a day time as the **existing moderators?**

Comment: @ColleenV I just want to say 'Thank You'. I didn't even know you were a moderator until today (I have been here for two months only). My mouse got clicked on your profile name, which redirected me to your profile page where I saw this post linked. I don't know what happened with the SE that so many people were fired or _unjustly removed_. You were so welcoming to me when I first came here and started participating. You showed me how to write effective answers with good formatting. I can only think how unfortunate ELL would be with you not being a moderator anymore. Thank you once again.

Comment: It was below a question posted earlier on Meta. I was observing the fact that the post was  downvoted, and the only comments visible were those telling the OP that SE is not a place to chat and ergo all the other comments had been deleted.

Comment: When I returned and saw the comment deleted, I posted this: *Ha ha my comment about comments being deleted even when the discussion tag exists, got deleted. The rules: extended discussion.must.be.exterminated.because.SE.is.not.a.forum. Exterminate. comments. Migrate.discussions.to.chat.Exterminate.fun.Exterminate.human.interactions. But somehow it's not always consistent, see here?* the link was to another question which had over 20 comments. Maybe more. None were complimentary, but the discourse was civil.

Comment: Meta can go to ****. I can't be asked to reply to the mod team. I know who wrote the letter I can tell their style, and maybe everyone on the team agreed on the course of action. Apparently the comments do not "spark joy". Well, the ban is a little upsetting but not surprising. The comnents were not directed at any user. Just me being sour.

Comment: @Mari-LouA They suspended you on Meta again? They don’t even pretend to be fair do they? They are very very sensitive about Meta being called toxic. Maybe the criticism hits [too close to home](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/close+to+home). I was just beating the dead horse that the comment system is broken: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383022/the-2022-community-a-thon-has-begun/383670?noredirect=1#comment1279895_383670 Maybe it will help.

Comment: Suspended for 12 months. In case you're too young to remember, the 2nd comment was me mimicking the Daleks in the 1970s BBC Dr Who series. Ha! I am the one being exterminated.

Comment: Posting the link to the question here because I cannot follow posts while under suspension https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383686/moving-comments-to-chat-kills-discussion

Comment: Comments, the ones about my suspension, have all been deleted. The post is not about me, so it makes sense to delete off-topic comments albeit related to the announcement. I wonder who tipped off the WP moderators, who contacted staff earlier in the year, that their site was in a state of abandonment.

Comment: Men get suspended too. I don't think this is a sexist issue, but I do think one particular mod and one CM  view me in a *very* negative light.

Comment: @Mari-LouA NYC is a fun place to visit. I haven't been for a long time, but even back then it was expensive. Hope they see reason and lift your suspension. I still can't believe they gave you such a long one.