# Election check-in 2023: Who's interested in stepping up and being a moderator here?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

One of our most recently elected Moderators, David Siegel, is no longer a Mod here, which leaves Laurel and me as the only active Mods, so we are thinking about holding an election to find someone to fill his shoes.

This question is to test for willingness of community members to step up and self-nominate before we decide to hold an election. If you're interested in running, **please leave an answer below**. Note that this is not an official election nomination thread, so it doesn't commit us to holding an election, and neither does answering here commit you to running in any election.

### Some info about the job

Official requirements:

- at least 18 years old
- at least 300 reputation points
- no suspensions on any site in the SE network in the previous 12 months

Nice-to-haves:

- some familiarity with the [review queues](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review)
- some participation on [ELL Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com)

From [CollenV's answer here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5626/113306):

> Things to know about being a moderator on ELL:
>
> - You don't have to log in every day... or even every other day. The amount of time you have to spend moderating is very flexible. If you need to be away from the site for a longer period of time you can set yourself as inactive without needing to resign.
> - You don't have to be an expert in English. A moderator's job doesn't involve answering questions about English. You just need to be able to communicate in English well enough to communicate with ELL community members, and read well enough understand the various SE codes, policies and other documents attached to this site.
> - The types of flags you handle on ELL are usually pretty mundane. If there's any situation you don't feel comfortable moderating, you can always ask someone else on the mod team or from the company's "Community Manger" (CM) team for help.
> - You don't have to have a lot of reputation to be a moderator, but you should have some experience with the review queues and be familiar with Stack Exchange policies and content guidelines. As a moderator, you will be able to close or reopen a question with a single vote, delete comments and posts, lock or add notices to posts, etc. The rest of the mod team will help you, but you may not be able to convince users to vote for you if you seem like you know very little.

More details of the responsibilities of a Mod can be found at the [FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/295232).

---

Note that we cannot hold an election until next year due to the upcoming holidays.

Comment: "Laurel and I are thinking about holding an election". What about the other current diamond moderators: [Em](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/36187/em), [Glorfindel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/18673/glorfindel), and [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r)?

Comment: There are five moderators. Aren't they enough to cover all the moderator's tasks in the main site? If they aren't enough, what are the tasks that require the additional moderator? (I am asking because that could be relevant to somebody who is offering to be moderator.)

Comment: @NikeDattani Em, Glorfindel, and J.R. are no longer active as Mods. I've modified the question to add this info

Comment: @apaderno See my comment above to Nike Dattani

Comment: @gotube why are they still diamond mods then? Why not have them removed? I guess for you to do that, you would need a majority of the diamond moderators to vote the other ones out, and right now the "active" diamond mods are the minority, and the "inactive" ones that ought to be removed, are the majority. I guess it would have been better to deal with this earlier, when it was only one or two diamond mods that were inactive. Now our best bet is probably to convince them to resign. I think having three diamond mods that are so inactive that you're saying it publicly, is a pretty big problem.

Comment: I've now looked at the activity of those other three diamond moderators. Non-diamond users can't see ***all*** diamond moderator activity (such as the handling of flags), but I do agree that [Em hasn't done much since 2021](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/36187/em?tab=activity). Glorfindel was very active with reviews until June 4th (the "strike" started on June 5th) and recently became active with reviews 12 hours ago (the above comments about inactivity started 13 hours ago). When a mod is doing that much reviewing, usually it also means handling of flags. But you certainly know better.

Comment: @NikeDattani I can't share any mod-only information, but yes, there are only two of us actively doing Mod stuff.

Comment: Some of these comments might suggest that I should withdraw my answer below, but I won't.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey your comment is extremely cryptic, as if it's cryptic by design.

Comment: @NikeDattani - OK. I was saying that I might not like to be a moderator if my actions, or their perceived lack, would attract the kind of scrutiny that comments like yours above suggest.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey All Mod work is open to the scrutiny of the users in one way or another. Some of it is visibly tied to your account --like closing questions, or deleting anything-- while other things aren't --like dismissing flags and sending disciplinary messages. But even these things can (and will) be scrutinized because it's clear *some mod* did it. The *amount* of mod work done by an individual mod is only visible to SE staff and other ELL Mods.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification! Once a user becomes a diamond moderator, they remain one for the rest of their life, unless a majority of the other diamond moderators elect to remove them (but I'm not aware of this ever happening across the ~200 sites in 15+ years), or they get removed by the SE company (I've only seen this happen to a handful of mods, out of 1000+ that have existed). You get extraordinary powers, channels to speak directly to SE employees, and you never have to run for re-election to keep your spot. It's fair that we want mods to remain more active than other high-rep others!

Comment: @gotube - yes. I understand. Perhaps I should say that I was a moderator on a site called Able2Know for a while, and retired hurt.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The job does require a thick skin sometimes, but there's always a large team of people to consult about any doubt, including fellow ELL Mods, all the other Mods network-wide (we have a very active private chat room for all of us), and SE staff.

Comment: @NikeDattani As far as I'm aware, other Mods cannot vote to remove a Mod -- they can only retire or be removed by SE staff. Where did you get that info?

Comment: @gotube I learned about it ages ago, in 2018, but by searching "moderator meta stack exchange vote remove" on Google, the first link was marked as a duplicate of [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336173/391772) which says "**The Moderator Action Review Process is a process for allowing a team of moderators to remove one of their own** This process is for those rare situations where communication with one member has completely broken down and the team as a whole feels they cannot continue to work together.)" I haven't read more than that today, but I think this is a place to start!

Comment: When you say “mod stuff” do you mean more than handling flags? Is there a queue of unhandled flags? It’s not a mod’s responsibility to keep review queues cleared for example… if the community isn’t doing that, the solution isn’t more moderators.

Comment: Even if there's not a queue of unhandled flags, there's other reasons why a site might want there to be more than just two active ◆moderators. I'm active daily on a site that has about 7x fewer questions/day compared to ELL, and there's two ◆moderators that are active and reachable, yet still we often need more (especially during certain hours of the day). That's a site that has almost 0 conflict, and had exactly 0 suspensions from 2021-2022 compared to 84 suspensions on ELL. If gotube and Laurel feel that more ◆ help is needed, I support that and don't feel I need to question their reasoning.

Comment: @NikeDattani Having been an ELL mod, I am familiar with this site's mod needs and how different mods have different levels of activity. Em was always good about handling flags if there were any to handle even if not doing many reviews. JR is less engaged than he used to be, but is unlikely IMO to leave flags unhandled. I would like to know if the # of flags is unmanageable. I have concerns if this election is because "we need more people with unilateral votes to keep the queues under control" because that is a solution which would be very harmful to this community in the long run.

Comment: It's important for mods to be transparent, so I'm not going to feel bad about asking for more information about what is motivating this election, and what the two out of five moderators believe is  an appropriate amount of what sorts of activity for a mod. Mods are supposed to be exception handlers, not ELL super users.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of unilateral close votes except for certain types of close reasons. Asking if the number of flags is unmanageable, is a fair question. I do think it's important to know what's motivating the election (I just assumed that it was because the other 3 were not actively enough helping the 2 more active ones, but if you think there's some other motivation which wasn't transparent enough, such as wanting to hammer the 67 close-vote reviews, it's fair to ask that). Since Em has not done a single "publicly visible" thing since June 2021, I doubt Em is helping much with flags.

Comment: @NikeDattani Mods don't have to do anything publicly visible to do the job they volunteered to do. Obviously Em has been active enough to prevent being removed for inactivity like David was. I was a very active mod, checking in multiple times a day, doing bunches of reviews but it wasn't necessary. Being that active probably hurt ELL in some ways. Mods can unintentionally dominate the community. It's really hard to have power to 'fix' things and not use it. Maybe I kept ELL from having a healthy number of reviewers because I handled too much and made it less rewarding for others.

Comment: @ColleenV I hear you and can relate to many of your points, but when a user's "all actions" page shows absolutely ***zero*** actions since June 2021 and we're about 1 month away from 2024, my ***personal*** opinion is that it is inappropriate for that user to be a diamond moderator on the site, no matter how many flags they are handling, and no matter how many fires they are extinguishing in chat. According to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if8TS.png), the user has probably not handled any flags in the last 7 days at least, but that is taking "benefit-of-the-doubt" to an extremum.

Comment: @ColleenV It was more of a "wow, gotube can't take a vacation without the flag queue growing" deal. While I'm also here (especially if there's urgent stuff), I would rather have another active mod. Regarding *I have concerns if this election is because "we need more people with unilateral votes to keep the queues under control"* I've thought long and hard about the close votes queue (yes, it's too big) and I think the solution is to change the close reason text so that fewer close votes are cast. We can also set up better new user onboarding. All of that will be easier with a new mod.

Comment: @NikeDattani You could suggest an additional public activity requirement for mods in a Meta SE post. This meta post isn't the time or place for that.

Comment: @Laurel Thanks. It's always better to have more capacity than just barely enough. wrt review queues I wonder if ELL just needs to get more people engaged. There are enough active users that have the privilege; I wonder why they don't participate in the queues.  Solving that issue would be better than giving the few who do participate more influence or discouraging people from close voting IMO.

Comment: @Laurel I was responding to ColleenV's comments. The conversation unfolded the way that it did in an organic way and I wasn't thinking "here's my chance to insert my views on something without making a new Meta post about it" and I also wasn't thinking "I better not reply to the last comment in which I was pinged because it's not the time and place for it". Hopefully we can all see that everyone in this comment chain has been acting in good faith so far.

Comment: @ColleenV I see that Laurel said "I think the solution is to change the close reason text so that fewer close votes are cast" and you replied with "I wonder why they don't participate in the queues. Solving that issue would be better than giving the few who do participate more influence IMO". How would changing the text of the close-vote reasons to reduce the number of times that people close-vote, give close-vote reviewers more influence? On some sites, only 3 votes are necessary for question closure, and that gives voters "more influence" but that's not what Laurel is suggesting, or is it?

Comment: @NikeDattani Because another tool that has been used to 'fix' queue issues is to reduce the number of votes required. I'm not arguing with Laurel's exact approach, I just don't think it's a problem mods can solve by focusing on the number of things in the queue.

Comment: @ColleenV When I say "Mod stuff", I mean handling flags, sending mod messages, and communicating with each other about other things. The review queue length didn't enter into *that* discussion, though we have discussed it – it's one of the "other things".

Answer (score 4):

Without committing to running, I will say that I am interested.

Comment: My first choice would be to vote for @ColleenV if she would only stand again, but I think [that ain't gonna happen,](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5099/i-am-resigning-as-moderator) so you can probably count on my vote if it comes to it. But so far as this preliminary page is concerned, I'm just gonna upvote *anyone* who throws their hat in the ring here. If the particular two "active" mods we have right now think they'd like another pair of hands, I have complete faith in their judgement - and there need to be candidates if we're gonna have an election.

Answer (score 4):

I am interested in being a moderator on ELL.